# Scrapy returns 400-error when trying to scrape Ajax call page

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape https://wegotthiscovered.com/reviews/ which uses Ajax pagination. I tried everything but it returns none or http-status code 400. Can anyone help in resolving this?

```py
import json
import scrapy
from..items import xyzItem

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'abc'
    data = {"id":"infinite_scroll_1","order":"","orderby":"","catnames":"reviews","postnotin":"900303,899404,898188,897386,896672,893944,895290,895136,892571,892412,891795,887847","timestampbefore":'1589354802'}
    headers = {"content-type": "application/json"}
    url = 'https://wegotthiscovered.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=self.url,
            method='POST',
            body=json.dumps(self.data),
            headers=self.headers,
            meta={'index': 0}
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        items = xyzItem()
        i = 1
        movie_title = response.css('h4').css('::text').getall() 
        # movie_text = response.css('.summary').xpath('text()').getall() 
        movie_id = response.css('h4').css('::attr(href)').getall()   


        li = items['movie_title']
        for i in range(len(li)):
            li_split =  li[i].split(" ")
            #print(movietitle)
            #if 'Review:' in li_split or 'review:' in li_split or 'Review' in li_split or 'review' in li_split:
            outputs = DeccanchronicleItem()
            outputs['page_title'] = li[i]
            # outputs['review_content'] = items['movie_text'][i]
            outputs['review_link'] = items['movie_id'][i]
            yield outputs

        page = response.meta['index'] + 1
        self.data['index'] = page
        yield scrapy.Request(self.url, headers=self.headers, method='POST', body=json.dumps(self.data), meta={'index': page})
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your code is that you don't use a correct `request`:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wegotthiscovered'
    data = {
        "id":"infinite_scroll_1",
        "order":"",
        "orderby":"",
        "catnames":"reviews",
        "postnotin":"900303,899404,898188,897386,896672,893944,895290,895136,892571,892412,891795,887847",
        "timestampbefore":'1589363845'
    }
    headers = {
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
        'referer': "https://wegotthiscovered.com/reviews/",
    }
    url = 'https://wegotthiscovered.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'
    start_urls = ['https://wegotthiscovered.com/reviews/'] # I used this to get cookies BEFORE POST request

    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(
            url=self.url,
            method='POST',
            callback=self.parse_search,
            formdata={
                'page': '2',
                'action': 'face3_infinite_scroll',
                'attrs': json.dumps(self.data),
            }
            ,
            headers=self.headers,
            meta={'index': 0}
        )

    def parse_search(self, response):
        items = xyzItem()
        i = 1
        movie_title = response.css('h4').css('::text').getall() 
        # movie_text = response.css('.summary').xpath('text()').getall() 
        movie_id = response.css('h4').css('::attr(href)').getall()   


        li = items['movie_title']
        for i in range(len(li)):
            li_split =  li[i].split(" ")
            #print(movietitle)
            #if 'Review:' in li_split or 'review:' in li_split or 'Review' in li_split or 'review' in li_split:
            outputs = DeccanchronicleItem()
            outputs['page_title'] = li[i]
            # outputs['review_content'] = items['movie_text'][i]
            outputs['review_link'] = items['movie_id'][i]
            yield outputs

        page = response.meta['index'] + 1
        self.data['index'] = page
        yield scrapy.Request(self.url, headers=self.headers, method='POST', body=json.dumps(self.data), meta={'index': page})
```

By the way, **your parsing section will not work** because you need to process JSON response (parse 'html' section from it).

**UPDATE** Everything works on my side (HTML contains a list of movies):

```
2020-05-16 00:20:23 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-05-16 00:20:23 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-05-16 00:20:23 [wegotthiscovered] INFO: Spider opened: wegotthiscovered
2020-05-16 00:20:23 [wegotthiscovered] INFO: Spider opened: wegotthiscovered
2020-05-16 00:20:23 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-05-16 00:20:24 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://wegotthiscovered.com/reviews/> (referer: None)
2020-05-16 00:20:30 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://wegotthiscovered.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php> (referer: https://wegotthiscovered.com/reviews/)
```

Either your IP is banned or you don't run my code.

Comment: after this also same error continues its throwing. Can you help me out.

2020-05-15 21:41:45 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://wegotthiscovered.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php> (referer: https://wegotthiscovered.com/reviews/)
2020-05-15 21:41:45 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://wegotthiscovered.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed